# How to show the dropdown list based on the picklist values

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, dropdown

I have an angular application in that I have to show the dropdown list based on the picklist values.

**.service.ts**

```
 public getLists() {
    let baseUrl = `/endpoint`;
    this._restfulService
      .restfulGetData(baseUrl)
      
      .subscribe(
        (LookupData: LookupData) => {
          if (LookupData) {
            this.option1data = LookupData.option1Data;
            this.option2data = LookupData.option2Data;
            this.option3data = LookupData.option3Data;
            this.option4data = LookupData.option4Data;
            
 }
        },
        (err) => {
          console.error(err);
        }
      );
  }
```

**.component.html**

```
 <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <label for="action"> <b>Category</b></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
              <select>
               
                <option value="" disabled [selected]="true"></option>
                <option>option1</option>
                <option>option2</option>
                <option>option3</option>
                <option>option4</option>
        </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

 <div class="row>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-3>
              <label for="action"> <b>Lists</b></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
              <select>
               <option value="" disabled [selected]="true"></option>
                <option>
                 
              //In this dropdown I have to show the lists based on the selection of picklists
                </option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

So In tha above code if I select option1 from the picklist I have to show the option1Data dropdownlist etc..

can anyone helpme on this

Comment: please post code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: @E.Maggini I tried for showing the one dropdown list for one picklist  <option *ngFor="let list of options"  [value]="option1.ID">  {{ option1.Name }} </option>  But for selecting other ones I got stuck could you please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <label for="action"> <b>Lists</b></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
      <select>
        <option disabled selected="true">Select pick</option>
        <option *ngFor="let items of LookupData" [ngValue]="items.name">
          {{ items.name }}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

please put the above code in the HTML file. Hope this code will helpful to you

Comment: the above code is not working